# Is there are way to "calculate" the guids for a GPT partition table?

Tags: partitioning, gpt, guid

There are specific reserved guids like `{DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC}` for a windows partition or `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}` for an unused partition.

Where do these values come from? Are they somehow fabricated, or are they just randomly generated and afterwards registered?

Does not seem very rational to use a supposedly "random" scheme to create specific identifiers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does not seem very rational to use a supposedly "random" scheme to create specific identifiers.

Actually, it seems very rational.

Back in the old days of the original IBM MBR format, we used an 8-bit identifier for "partition type". This was back in 1982 or so.

This might have been sufficient when we only foresaw a small number of possibilities, but in between different variants of DOS, other PC-based OSes, and a few other systems that needed their own (sometimes a few different) partition type identifiers, it was pretty easy to run out of choices.

GPT is designed to resolve the issues of the MBR that have cropped up in the last about 35 years. Now that we have many times more storage space available in the size of a fingernail than a huge storage array had then, we can afford to "waste" a few extra bytes on ensuring that given the laws of physics as we understand them we can *never* run out of choices. (Roughly speaking, there simply isn't enough matter on Earth to even *store* a single copy of every valid GUID with current known storage methods. Every currently living person on Earth could generate some 10^25 GUIDs and the risk of collision would still only be marginal.)

GPT, or GUID Partition Table, uses GUIDs for more or less everything. Since the primitive is already being used, there doesn't seem to be any major reason to use something different for the partition type.

GUIDs are generated randomly, according to a fixed format. So you could pick some "special" value, or you could just generate a single GUID and call that one "special". There is nothing magical that makes one particular GUID value more or less special than any other. About the only really "special" GUID is the all-zeroes GUID, but that is only because we generally treat all-zeroes or all-ones values as special in computing.

So, once you have decided to use GUIDs, and you need to define some specific value, you simply **generate a random GUID and then announce by decree that "this GUID has that meaning".** Anyone who wants to be able to interoperate with you must then treat that particular GUID as having that specific meaning and not some other.

Comment: @DonQuestion - No; That wouldn't be realistic.

Comment: It stands for `Unique` as in **Globally** **Unique** **Id**entifier

Comment: As Michael explains, each identifier that is defined as a specific purpose, in reality there reality are not that many that are actually used.

Comment: Each partition has a partition *type* GUID, and a partition-*specific* GUID. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_entries

Comment: @DonQuestion Wikipedia lists 85 partition type GUIDs. That's not a whole lot.

Comment: @DonQuestion Why should I? Just put them in a dictionary or other type of list, preferably loaded from disk so the list can be easily updated. Problem solved. It's not like most people inspect the MBR, let alone GPT, manually in its on-disk representation anyway.